# PHP Cache Control for browser to only cache part of page

Tags: php, html, caching

Currently I am using `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` in my PHP script to tell the browser to reload everything every time. But this is totally unnecessary because I only want a certain piece of code reload and have stuff such as images cached - especially because it's a mobile page.

Is there any way to ensure images gets cached but not the text? Or anything like that?

*Take Note: Javascript is not allowed.*

Comment: You can force "may be cached" headers to be sent with images via some Apache tuning. But there is NO way to signal that "lines 40-302 should not be cached" in a file. The cache headers apply to the entire contents of a page, not individual parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images are retrieved from a different HTTP request than your PHP pages, they can be cached on not the html. [This](http://www.samaxes.com/2008/04/htaccess-gzip-and-cache-your-site-for-faster-loading-and-bandwidth-saving/) page describes caching images in quite a bit of detail.

As far as caching a portion of the page, why can't you use javascript? A reasonable approach is to cache the page till the end of time, and then make an ajax request for the non-cache-able content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't use JS because the page can't have JS. It has to cover mobile phones, even the basic ones which does not even support CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, browsers can't request for a part of a page without a specially crafted request or using Javascript.

You could try iframes, but I don't recommend that at all.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. What I also thought. Just waiting, maybe someone has some sort of solution.